# AOE3: Multiplayer Game Through LAN lags

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Age Of Empires III : Lag in  Multiplayer game ( LAN )](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/age-of-empires-iii-lag-in-multiplayer-game-lan)

Hi all,

I am trying to play **Age Of Empires 3** through LAN between my PC and Laptop. My PC and Laptop is connected by a Ethernet cable through a modem. Now I have 256MB ATI RADEON graphics card and I am able to play the game very smoothly, even with high graphics settings enabled when in a single Player game. But when playing in LAN, I see a lag for every second. But what confuses me is that, there is no such lag in my PC. The game in PC runs the same, even in Multiplayer game. What might be the problem here... Any help is appreciated... Thanks...

Comment: Probably belongs to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It sounds like network lag.  How fast is the network and your connections?  And does the host have a good computer?

Comment: Wait, wasn't this asked 9 hours before the one you refer to it being a clone of? I guess it was migrated after the other one had been asked...

Comment: Yep, and the other one is a better question.  I think the migration process needs some work, personally.